How to Showing 2 Decimal Points on Numeric Column in R
I am racking my brain to understand why round function is not working in a simple data frame. I want to see 2 decimal point after the end of each value in the column numeric_col while not changing the data type to character.
This is the data frame I am working on.
df <- structure(list(ttext = c("text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", 
"text5", "text6", "text7", "text8", "text9", "text10"), numeric_col = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

The code I wrote to see the 2 decimal points is:
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
    df <- df %>% 
      mutate(numeric_col = round(numeric_col,2))

For some reason the data frame doesnt add the 2 decimal points in the numeric column.
attached is the snapshot of both.


Your input data has no decimal point component, so there’s nothing to be rounded.

@KonradRudolph So how can I add 2 decimal point on this column numeric_col ?

I’m not sure what you mean. Do you just want to append .00 to each value in that column?

Yeah. I want the column to show 1.00, 2.00, 3.00 etc. While ensuring that the column data type doesnt change to Char as I have to perform numeric operations after that.

That’s simply not possible. You are confusing representation and value. The .00 would be part of the representation, not of the value (1, 1.0 and 1.00 are all the same value), and round() operates on the value. To change the way the values are represented you would need to format them as character strings. — That said, the ‘pillar’ package might be what you’re after: it allows you to change the default representation of values inside a given tibble. Maybe you could add a specific formatter for your tibble to add decimal points.

@KonradRudolph if not round. I am open to have any other function as well. I just want 2 decimal points without converting the column to Char.

My comment wasn’t specific to round(), the distinction between representation and value is a general truth. That said, have a look at Edward’s answer, which uses (an undocumented function of) the ‘pillar’ package I mentioned. This still changes the column type, but maybe that’s acceptable for your use-case.

You can use the num function from the pillar/tibble package:
mutate(df, numeric_col=num(numeric_col, digits=2))
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   ttext  numeric_col
   <chr>    <num:.2!>
 1 text1         1.00
 2 text2         2.00
 3 text3         3.00
 4 text4         4.00
 5 text5         5.00
 6 text6         6.00
 7 text7         7.00
 8 text8         8.00
 9 text9         9.00
10 text10       10.00

Although the function is described as experimental, you can still perform numeric calculations on these vectors, but possibly at your own risk!

Does the num() function create an issue while exporting the dataframe from R to excel. I saw that while trying to write the dataframe, the excel output is getting more decimal points that 2. Even though we have specified it to be 2.

That's an Excel issue, not R. You can easily tell Excel how many digits to show for numeric columns.

Cant we control what we give to excel from R. So if we limit the decimal to 2 digits in R, excel would not be able to make up the other digits right.

That may be possible, but would be another question.
